# Dealing with elder siblings

Tags: practical-islam, family

I am an 18yr old Muslim boy. My elder sister always feels she can boss me around. She's just 2 years older than me. Does an elder siblings have any power over a younger sibling?

Answer (score 1):

At-Tirmidhi (1919) narrated from Anas that the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “He is not one of us who does not show compassion towards our younger ones and show respect to our older ones.”

Those who have guardianship and a responsibility to discipline a person include his mother and his older brother.